# How to update Predecessor or PredecessorList Object in Smartsheet Python SDK

Tags: python, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have a loop that creates a parent row and a variable number of child rows. I would like to update the Predecessor field of the child row with the prior child row number (when more than one child row is added). I am having difficulty adding the 2 required arguments to the 'cell.object_value' object (object_type & predecessors).

```
for key, value in record.items():    
    new_cell = ss.models.Cell()
    if k == 'Predecessors':
        pred = []
        pred_update = {}
        pred_update['rowId'] = predecessor_row_id
        pred_update['type'] = 'FS'
        pred.append(pred_update)

        row = ss.Sheets.get_row(sheet_id, predecessor_row_id)
        new_cell.object_value = str(row.row_number)
        new_cell.object_value.predecessors = pred
        new_cell.object_type = "PREDECESSOR_LIST"
```

EDIT:
The code runs without error however the information contained in the new_cell.object_value.predecessors argument is not being transferred into SmartSheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting predecessors is little tricky. You were on the right track. However, when you set the value on the cell, you just need to set the `object_value`. Like this:

```
# init the object_value for predecessor cell
pred_cell.object_value = ss_client.models.ObjectValue()

# set the object_type to PREDECESSOR_LIST
pred_cell.object_value.object_type = "PREDECESSOR_LIST"

# set the object_value for the cell with the PredecessorList
pred_cell.object_value = pred_list
```

A full Gist of the operation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/stmcallister/dfbd7d6ae68e6ccf7d5c1eef41d5f0a6).

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. I read over the documentation multiple times and printed the attributes of every predecessor object I could identify but would have never set it up correctly. Thanks.

Comment: the full Gist link stmcallister gives is what did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

`predecessors` is a property of the [object value](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#objectvalue-object), not the cell directly.

```
new_cell.objectValue.predecessors = pred
```

Comment: Thanks, you have helped me get one step closer. However, I am still having an issue setting the object_type which I believe is preventing the predecessor field from having its intended effect on the timeline.